# How to unzip the file_name.csv.gz files to .csv

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to unzip files which are in *.csv.gz format to .csv format.

When I tried with these commands `$ gzip -d file.gz` and `$ gzip -f file.gz`, it is showing like

```
gzip: IQ.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: Envoy.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: compressed data not read from a terminal. Use -f to force decompression.
For help, type: gzip -h
```

Please help me on this to how to unzip.

Comment: I'm not an expert in that field, but seeing your errors I would say there's no file names IQ.gz or envoy.gz where you run the command...

Comment: No, File is there. when i tried with -f option, it is not unzipping and taking too much time.

Comment: Is there a space in your filename (e.g. "IQ Envoy.gz")? If you try to gzip -d hello world.gz, gzip will search for the files "hello(.gz)" and "world.gz". Try gzip -d "hello world.gz" instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.csv.gz' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 gzip -d
```

Should sort you, alternatively:

```
find . -name '*.csv.gz' -exec gzip -d {} \;
```

will also work. These are recursive so they will go into subdirs.

Comment: Hi, after using your command, my file name becomes 13232,1140,171540,1,"41401" and the content become empty. I am not sure why. Would you mind help or teach me how to undo the command? Thank you!

Comment: Ask a separate question and link it here, with more detail and I'll be happy to take a look?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/664633/unzip-xxx-csv-gz-to-procedures-icd-csv. This is the updated link and thank you!